# Bing Maps REST Services C# API - implementing httprequests and argument packing/unpacking

Tags: c#, .net, maps, bing-maps

I am searching for Bing maps API comparable to:
https://github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net

I don't want to send Http requests, I don't need to know anything about how data is fetched. I need API which will pack all this in some nice classes, implement and hide all these requests and packing which are not interesting for me and it is ready to include in windows application after short study.
Also it needs to work on windows 7.

This is exactly what I need, but it is not finished yet:
https://github.com/advancedrei/Bing.RestClient

Comment: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: Good point. It is even funny how it matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has exactly what I need, but it also implements many other providers like Google and OpenStreetMap, and has display controls:
[GMap.NET - Great Maps for Windows Forms & Presentation](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Bing Maps has a dedicated WPF map control that can also be used in WinForm applications. You can find documentation on the WPF control here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx

Here is a blog post on how to use the WPF control in a WinForm application:

http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/using-bing-maps-in-winforms/

To do geocoding/routing with this control you would use the Bing Maps REST services:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-amp-tricks.aspx

Here are a couple other blog posts on the Bing Maps WPF control that you might find interesting:

http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/entity-framework-5-bing-maps-wpf/

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2012/09/12/esri-shapefiles-and-bing-maps-wpf.aspx

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/10/03/draggable-pushpins-in-bing-maps-net.aspx

Alternatively, if you want an open source map control that also support Bing Maps tiles (still needs a Bing Maps key) then take a look at this project: http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/

Note that internal apps using Bing maps require a license. The same is true for most other mapping API's.

Comment: Although this is nice answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454496 ;) it is not for this question. I was looking for something to implement all these httprequests, and deliver me nice objects and classes for geo objects from routing, search etc. I admit that question is not so clear, only when you look at example you can be sure ;)

Comment: Ok, in that case the links in the middle of my response on using the REST services for geocoding and routing are relevant. Also, I wrote a library that does a lot of this, but it's for Windows Store apps. You should be able to pull a lot of the code from it. You can find it here: http://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: These are relevant if I want to implement code myself. But I have hoped that someone else handled all this httprequests and packing and exposed nice set of classes and methods for me. mapstoolbox is other thing, its more about supporting other spatial data formats, not handling Bing map stuff like Directions, Traffic, Search results... But I'm giving you thumbs up because this is also very useful code for me. Implements some tasks I need, but much more lightweight than other similar libraries. Thanks!

Comment: Look in the Bing folder of the mapstoolbox for libraries for the Bing Maps REST services. If you are creating a Windows 8 or Web app using JavaScript then there are nice libraries that wrap the REST services right in the Bing Maps control so you don't have to handle the http requests.

Comment: I can see classes for Jason, but I think they are also on MSDN, what is missing is access layer for this calls, check for example: https://github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net/tree/master/src/Google.Maps/Direction

Comment: Yes, this library has a bunch of JSON classes for not only the REST services but for the POI data in the Spatial Data Services. There really is no need for an access layer as most developers only need to do one or two things with the service and that can be done in the same, if not less lines of code using the service as it is now.

Comment: If someone need one or two things, than he can download classes from MSDN, write these few lines, and skip using 3rd party lib, at least for the REST part, if he needs Shape support or something like that than OK.