# WPF map control with supported directions, search

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps, wpf-controls, bing-maps

I am searching Windows 7 compatible WPF/WinForms control that can display maps, calculate directions, perform searching and other map operations.
Basically, it all doesn't have to integrated in one solution, it can be something like one control for maps display (Google or Bing or Nokia or OSM) and some library that supports all other operations, but it should be easy to integrate this two, like draw calculated route on map or fetch calculated routes from map. What i don't want is that all is bundled in map control and not accessible from code behind, like having some maps.google in WebBrowserControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is awsome, it has everything I need, and much more:
[GMap.NET - Great Maps for Windows Forms & Presentation](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I will update this answer and accept it after few days of play with this. But this looks more big and more powerful than I expected to find.

Answer (score 5):

Bing Maps has a dedicated WPF map control that can also be used in WinForm applications. You can find documentation on the WPF control here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx

Here is a blog post on how to use the WPF control in a WinForm application:

http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/using-bing-maps-in-winforms/

To do geocoding/routing with this control you would use the Bing Maps REST services:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-amp-tricks.aspx

Here are a couple other blog posts on the Bing Maps WPF control that you might find interesting:

http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/entity-framework-5-bing-maps-wpf/

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2012/09/12/esri-shapefiles-and-bing-maps-wpf.aspx

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/10/03/draggable-pushpins-in-bing-maps-net.aspx

Comment: This is nice control, also REST API is nice. I found this to pair with: https://github.com/advancedrei/Bing.RestClient but it is not finished for Directions.

Answer (score 2):

Displaying Google Maps in a WPF application can involve using the Google Maps API for Flash or the Google Maps JavaScript API.

You might find something interested and much similar to what you are looking for [WPF Map App: WPF Meets Google Geocoding and Static Maps APIs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238551/WPF-Map-App-WPF-meets-Google-Geocoding-Static-Maps)

[image]

Comment: This is something similar to what I need, only I was hoping for more integrated solution, to have C# api that will hide all http/json stuff.

Comment: @watbywbarif: Did you tried the above solution located on codeproject?

Comment: It's a nice demo, but it would require much more work to integrate Directions API, if I don't find something with more features ill try to make something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your best bet would simply be to use the [Google Maps API for Javascript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) for front end display logic and then [Google's selection of web services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/) for any code-behind calculations, geocoding, routing etc.

There is no need for your solution to be entirely front end as you specify but obviously there is a need for front end mapping functionality. All of the services can be accessed directly from the RESTful Google services from your c# (or even ajaxed javascript), I don't understand the need for it to be specifically WPF?

Comment: This is extension for existing WPF app. I have found https://github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net, which resolves all http/json code, but i hoped that there is something more complete, with finished map control. I can write map control using this lib, or i can use WebBrowserControl and play more with JavaScript APIs, but this will require much more work and testing to integrate into current WPF app.

Comment: I would advise using and learning to use the API's directly seeing as Google updates fairly regularly and whatever library you end up with may not. I realize this will take more time and effort (and you're possibly on a tight schedule) but it will prevent problems further down the line. Obviously your decision though.

Comment: Good point, but as this project is open source, I can always update it myself if needed. But it seams quite possible I'll have to go deep into this, sooner or later ;)